# Probability of getting exactly $N/2$ heads when flipping a coin $N$ times

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I'm really stuck on this probability question. Any hints to help me get going would be great.

> Let $N$ be $1346$. Suppose you flip a fair coin $N$ times and let $H$ be the number of heads you get.
>
> $(a)$ What is the probability that $H$ is exactly $\frac{N}{2}$?

Comment: [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) (familiar with it?) with parameters $p=\frac12$ and $n=1346$. To find $P(H=673)$.

Comment: When p = q = 0.5, the binomial distribution formula simplifies to $P(k) = \frac{n\choose k}{2^n}$. Take it from there...

Comment: $\frac{\binom{N}{N/2}}{2^N}$

Answer (score 2):

The total number of combinations is $\color\red{2^N}$

The number of combinations with $\frac12N$ heads is $\color\green{\dbinom{N}{\frac12N}=\dfrac{N!}{(\frac12N)!\cdot(\frac12N)!}}$

So the probability to obtain $\frac12N$ heads is $\dfrac{\color\green{\dfrac{N!}{(\frac12N)!\cdot(\frac12N)!}}}{\color\red{2^N}}=\dfrac{N!}{(\frac12N)!\cdot(\frac12N)!\cdot2^N}$

Comment: For $N=1346$, the answer is approximately $2.17438712396048852183618132352068623937753056614743\%$.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a Binomial Probability Distribution. You can see more info on it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). In this case, you are looking for the probability of $\frac{1346}{2}=673$ successes out of 1346 trials with probability of success $p=0.5$, which gives us $\binom{1346}{673}(\frac{1}{2})^{1346}\approx0.02174.$